# Excel from web scraping

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I want to pull all 6 of these tables from [this website](https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-team-defensive-ranks-position) into my workbook. (vs All,vs PG,vs SG,vs SF,vs PF,vs C) When I try using the from web option in excel and selecting the table it just pulls in the headers. Why is that? Currently I have a paste now button and I goto the website, copy it and click the "Paste" button I created with a macro to clear current info and paste new values. I would like to eliminate me having to manually goto the website and copy the table. Is there another way to do it besides "From Web"

Comment: Generally questions posted here should include the code that you attempted with along with sample data and an explanation of the problem or any errors. See [ask] as well as how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are selecting the right table. There are two table elements. The first is just headers.  The second is headers + info. I am not sure you can use this method to get all the tabs though as the URL doesn't change and the content is javascript updated. You can see whether the [API](https://developers.swishanalytics.com/developers/new?protected=1) has anything to offer though it is gate-kept by staff who want to speak to you before issuing an API key.

Any easy way is to go VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls then use Internet Explorer to navigate to the page.

You can use a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) to target the table by its [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors) and another CSS selector [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) selector to target all the tab links so as to click them to update the table for each tab.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, hTable As HTMLTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim clipboard As Object, tabs As Object, iTab As Long
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-team-defensive-ranks-position"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set tabs = .document.querySelectorAll(".position.fastClick")

        For iTab = 0 To tabs.Length - 1

            If iTab > 0 Then
                tabs.item(iTab).Click
                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

            End If

            clipboard.SetText .document.querySelector("#stat-table").outerHTML
            clipboard.PutInClipboard

            With ws
                .Cells(GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 2, 1).PasteSpecial
            End With
        Next
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function
```

---

If you don't want to use the clipboard to copy paste the table you can loop its rows and table cells within rows.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, ws As Worksheet, tabs As Object, iTab As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-team-defensive-ranks-position"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set tabs = .document.querySelectorAll(".position.fastClick")

        For iTab = 0 To tabs.Length - 1
            If iTab > 0 Then
                tabs.item(iTab).Click
                While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
            End If

            WriteTable .document.querySelector("#stat-table"), GetLastRow(ws, 1) + 2, ws
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long
    With ws
        GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End Function

Public Sub WriteTable(ByVal hTable As HTMLTable, Optional ByVal startRow As Long = 1, Optional ByVal ws As Worksheet)

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim tSection As Object, tRow As Object, tCell As Object, tr As Object, td As Object, r As Long, C As Long, tBody As Object
    r = startRow
    With ws
        Dim headers As Object, header As Object, columnCounter As Long
        Set headers = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")
        For Each header In headers
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
            .Cells(startRow, columnCounter) = header.innerText
        Next header
        startRow = startRow + 1
        Set tBody = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
        For Each tSection In tBody
            Set tRow = tSection.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            For Each tr In tRow
                r = r + 1
                Set tCell = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                C = 1
                For Each td In tCell
                    .Cells(r, C).Value = td.innerText
                    C = C + 1
                Next td
            Next tr
        Next tSection
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I've been rather verbose with the WriteTable syntax to show the main table elements. A loop of table headers, table rows and table cells is sufficient.