# Extract data from web without identifier?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

How can I extract a table from a website https://www.lyngsat.com/tvchannels/in/Aaj-Tak.html to an excel which does not any identifier?

I want to Extract data from Table containing Satellite position, frequency, and encryption.

Previously, I tried using getElementsByTagName but there are too many tags for a different table on the page.

Comment: Should we guess which table it is you want?

Comment: It's the Table with Satellite position, frequency, and encryption.

Comment: Loop over all tables until you find one with "Position" in the second cell of the second row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use xmlhttp. The table you want is at index 11 (0 based indexing). I use clipboard as easy way to write out table. If you don't want to use clipboard you can loop rows and columns of the table as shown in `WriteTable` sub [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53135557/6241235)

This

```
html.querySelectorAll("table").item(11)
```

selects the table at that index in the response. Equivalent to

```
html.getElementsByTagName("table")(11)
```

There is another unique identifier, when used in combination with `table` type selector, in the output which is the table `border` attribute value of `1`:

[image]

so you could use

```
clipboard.SetText html.querySelector("table[border='1']").outerHTML
```

---

VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, clipboard As Object '<  VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft HTML Object Library
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.lyngsat.com/tvchannels/in/Aaj-Tak.html", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    clipboard.SetText html.querySelectorAll("table").item(11).outerHTML  ' html.querySelector("table[border='1']").outerHTML
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```